# computing slope on heavy tailed lognormal distribution

Tags: regression, distributions, hypothesis-testing, robust, lognormal-distribution

I have a heavy tailed logNormal distribution and i want to know if it's possible to make a linear regression in order to compute R² and slope for this data.

I make my linear regression on computed values log10(rank) and log10(population) (cf it's a rank size plot)

[image]

I don't know if it's a good method, especially in the case of heavy tailed distribution.

Do you know better/robust method to compute slope of lognormal distribution?

Comment: I am confused by this question because although it refers to a *lognormal* distribution, it appears to describe a *power* distribution (in which there is a linear relationship between the logarithm of the value and the logarithm of its quantile). Which one do you really mean and what precisely do you mean by the "slope" of a univariate dataset like this one?

Comment: @whuber With settlements of smaller sizes (like our simulation output) are included, the lognormal distribution provides
better fit than the Pareto model(Pumain, 1982) > [src](http://www.google.fr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CD4QFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.santafe.edu%2Fmedia%2Fworkingpapers%2F04-02-002.pdf&ei=xb-9UKC9BJO2hAfgg4DYAw&usg=AFQjCNG57tTF7Emu6_5ajKziL9p1cZsLpg&cad=rja).Most study in geography refer to the slope of the Pareto law adjusted to the population size distribution according to the so-called «rank size rule» by Zipf > [src](http://cybergeo.revues.org/3790)

Comment: Here slope = 0.907 for us

Comment: I'm still baffled. Do you wish to fit a lognormal distribution to data or must you have answers that somehow--it's unclear in what sense--"make a linear regression" to estimate parameters of the distribution? What information do you hope to obtain from this approach that would not be available from conventional distribution fitting methods such as Maximum Likelihood or Method of Moments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the aim is to fit a lognormal distribution, it would be most common to fit it by maximum likelihood (and with some reason).

This basically involved taking logs and [fitting a normal distribution to the logs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution#Maximum_likelihood_estimation_of_parameters) by ML.

The parameter estimates of that normal-on-the-log-scale are the ML estimates of the lognormal parameters.

A suitable method similar to (but different from) the one you seem to be proposing could work.